# SCCM downloading software updates is extremely slow

Tags: windows, deployment, wsus, sccm, automatic-updates

I have an SCCM 1606 server (a.k.a. SCCM 2016) configured with the Software Update role.  The server has been syncing with Microsoft every day for months now and all that is working correctly.  Earlier this morning, I configured an automatic deployment rule with the following criteria:

- Product: Windows 7 OR Office 2013
- Required: >=1 (meaning any update that is needed by at least one computer in the organization)
- Superseded: No
- Update classification: ALL (except AV definitions, which are handled by a different auto-deployment rule).
- Adds to an existing Software Update Group called `Workstation Updates`.
- Evaluates every 2nd Wednesday of each month (the day after Patch Tuesday).
- Deploys immediately to a test collection.

This query should produce a package of 391 updates as of right now.

After I created the rule, I ran it manually to make it effective today, and it began downloading the updates like it's supposed to.  That was 7 hours ago.  I've been checking the group throughout the day, and it is growing, but is doing so very very slowly.  As of this writing, it has only downloaded 15 items so far.  At this rate, it will take **weeks** to download them all!

I checked the content location, and there is about 8GB of data in there, so either the 15 updates it's downloaded so far are particularly big ones, or it has parallelized a bunch of them and the only ones showing in the console are the 15 that have completed?  Either way, 8 gigs in 7 hours is unacceptably slow.

The server as a whole is not very busy.  It only runs SCCM and it's hosting the database locally.  It's also hosting all the roles itself, so there are no dependencies on other servers on the network.  There are no other deployments going on right now, and I just checked with the help desk; no one has any computers imaging right now.

Task Manager shows the network activity is steady around 1Mb/sec with brief spikes to >10 Mb/sec.  We have a 60Mbit internet connection and it's solid at the moment, so that's not the issue.  CPU and memory are also good.

The server is definitely working on *something*, it's just taking its sweet time doing it.  What's going on here?  How can I check the status of these downloads?  And why are they taking so long?

Answer (score 1):

Please examine the log file patchdownloader.log on the site server.

It provides information about the process for downloading software updates from the update source specified in the software updates metadata to the download destination on the site server.

Using the URL copy from patchdownloader.log to download the update manually via IE.

Also, take a look at proxy settings.

netsh winhttp show proxy